# Coordinate transformation with GDAL replicating Geotools Java package transform

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotools, gdalwarp

We are developing an earth observation data processors utilizing GPU.

One of the operation trying to achieve is the coordinate transform. For some rasters the output CRS intended would be some local UTM zone. The baseline software comparing the results against is [ESA SNAP](https://github.com/senbox-org). It uses Geotools Java package for transforming coordinates. The following code is used to create raster boundaries:

```
CoordinateOperationFactory coordinateOperationFactory = CRS.getCoordinateOperationFactory(lenient);
CoordinateOperation operation = coordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(this.crs, targetCRS);
GeneralEnvelope transformed = CRS.transform(operation, this);
transformed.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(targetCRS);
ReferencedEnvelope target = new ReferencedEnvelope(transformed);
MathTransform transform = operation.getMathTransform();
JTS.transform(this, target, transform, numPointsForTransformation);
```

From ReferencedEnvelope.java (lenient = true, points for transformation = 200)

For example an envelope defined in WGS84/EPSG:4326:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -73.7121135, -50.0737113) ( 73d42'43.61"W, 50d 4'25.36"S)
Lower Left  ( -73.7121135, -51.9749523) ( 73d42'43.61"W, 51d58'29.83"S)
Upper Right ( -71.5799904, -50.0737113) ( 71d34'47.97"W, 50d 4'25.36"S)
Lower Right ( -71.5799904, -51.9749523) ( 71d34'47.97"W, 51d58'29.83"S)
Center      ( -72.6460520, -51.0243318) ( 72d38'45.79"W, 51d 1'27.59"S)
```

is converted to UTM 18S/EPSG:32718:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  588458.695, 4452379.281) ( 73d45'49.60"W, 50d 4'27.39"S)
Lower Left  (  588458.695, 4236220.841) ( 73d42'39.36"W, 52d 1' 3.33"S)
Upper Right (  744693.415, 4452379.281) ( 71d34'59.43"W, 50d 1'49.94"S)
Lower Right (  744693.415, 4236220.841) ( 71d26'14.77"W, 51d58'14.65"S)
Center      (  666576.055, 4344300.061) ( 72d37'28.15"W, 51d 1'43.26"S)
```

When calling `gdaltransform -s_srs WGS84 -t_srs epsg:32718 -output_xy` The results are:

```
-73.7121135, -50.0737113
592156.503084142 4452379.34508025
-73.7121135, -51.9749523
588461.657861387 4240964.41575646
-71.5799904, -50.0737113
744701.614550064 4447570.04868514
-71.5799904, -51.9749523
734882.965462416 4236222.58906634
```

Which are way off for some longitude values compared to GeoTools' `CRS.transform()`.

Another comparison with GDAL based tools is warping the original dataset processed in WGS84 to UTM 18S.

```
gdalwarp -ts 11112 15374  -r near -t_srs EPSG:32718 S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20220306T235614_20220306T235642_042207_0507B2_2270_tnr_Cal_IW1_deb_tc.tif S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20220306T235614_20220306T235642_042207_0507B2_2270_tnr_Cal_IW1_deb_tc_utm18s_gdalwarp_ts_near.tif
```

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  588461.655, 4452379.350) ( 73d45'49.45"W, 50d 4'27.38"S)
Lower Left  (  588461.655, 4236227.483) ( 73d42'39.21"W, 52d 1' 3.11"S)
Upper Right (  744706.220, 4452379.350) ( 71d34'58.79"W, 50d 1'49.91"S)
Lower Right (  744706.220, 4236227.483) ( 71d26'14.12"W, 51d58'14.42"S)
Center      (  666583.937, 4344303.417) ( 72d37'27.76"W, 51d 1'43.14"S)
```

Which is much closer and is sufficient for this purpose. However when trying to replicate these coordinates in C/C++ I cannot quite get the same results. I have been debugging the source code of `gdalwarp` and found out that instead of using `OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation()` a `GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer2()` is used. But when implementing it I get results more similar to `gdaltransform`. When further debugging I found that input dataset's information is used inside the `GDALWarpDirect()` and its ancestor calls. I also tried to call `GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer2()` while also supplying input dataset in WGS84 besides source and target SRS, but no avail. Inside the `GDALWarpDirect()` I can detect that points are created and a lot of transformations are done in order to estimate the points.

How to implement all that in pure C/C++ without actually invoking the `gdalwarp` itself. Only alternative I can think of is to copy the source code and try to assign exact same transform arguments etc, but it would get pretty heavy implementation trying to nail down all the details. How come the simple `gdaltransform` results deviate from Geotools package/gdalwarp one so much? Is it because of the estimation of earth curvature and/or some points not residing fully in UTM 18S ?

Comment: Just to confirm, have you considered that warping rotates the image and GDAL is reporting the corner coordinates of the envelope of the rotated image https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUndz.png?

Comment: are you sure everyone is using the same axis order through out?

Comment: @user30184 Yes I know. The input image itself was already 'warped' since being a Sentinel-1 terrain corrected radar image - hence no additional envelope creation is needed. An example - https://imgur.com/a/P9UzDgW

Comment: @IanTurton No they do not. gdalwarp handles it, the input has order of (1, 2) and output (2, 1). But this is not the point here - as a general I am asking how to transform coordinates similar to gdalwarp tool, which in turn is similar to Java's Geotools' package CRS.transform()

Comment: I tried the "Reprojection console" that comes with GeoServer as a demo application. The result for the first point `-73.7121135, -50.0737113` is `592156.5030841627 4452379.345078852` that is pretty close to what GDAL gives. Do you see any possibility that you are not comparing the same points?

Comment: @user30184 I pasted the points that were converted. Your result is similar to `gdaltransform`. Meanwhile I found out that using `GDALSuggestedWarpOutput2()` is giving me the box coordinates that are similar to original Java ESA SNAP solution. I think one cannot simply transform coordinates like that for raster corners. What `GDALSuggesterWarpOutput2()` does is that it iterates the edges of the box and transforms each step. Something vaguely similar that JTS.transform does. Hence probably simulating the curvature of the earth?

Comment: Please add a test case (input and output coordinates) for this "How come the simple gdaltransform results deviate from Geotools package/gdalwarp one so much?". I am not sure if you still think right about the corner coordinates. Corners in https://imgur.com/a/P9UzDgW as gdalinfo reports them are at the outmost black corners of the north-up rectangle, not at the corners of the net image area. After warping into UTM the original north-up rectangle rotates and gdalinfo reports the extents of a a new bigger envelope https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUndz.png.

Comment: You are right that warping is not as simple as transforming the corner coordinates. GDAL applies warping to a group of pixels (chunks) and I suppose that GeoTools does the same. The transformation between EPSG:4326 and UTM zones is so common that I would be surprised if GDAL and GeoTools produces much different results when both libraries are used correctly. As a visual check about GeoTools warping you could make a WMS layer with GeoServer. For pure C++ solution I think https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html is the starting point and the source code of gdalwarp can be used as a reference.